# Full width 2 div triangles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I imagine if there any ways to position divs like this (picture down below), so they can be animated (fadeinleft or something like that). I want my triganles be the same size and to add elements in them so they can be as in picture. I don't want padding or margin or border, so is there any way to do that using css/css3 ?

Full width and height, without padding and margin. The elements are not important, just want this 2 divs.

Comment: how the animation should be triggered?
as to the problem you could make a div for each big triangle using the css border styling trick[link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) and them use another div over top to hold the elements you want them animate them both as they move

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you can add tingle image in background. But without full width and height, without padding and margin, its not possible.